# Determine what process is talking to a remote port on Windows Server

Tags: powershell, connection, port, windows-server-2012-r2

I took over a product from a contractor at my place of work. The tool collects metainformation. The exact nature of the information isn't important to the question, but it exists as either a flat file and/or in a database. Somehow the contractor configured *something* on the server to forward logs (as text) to our Splunk forwarder. We don't *think* he's using the Splunk Forwarder, as we see no evidence of its existence (either installed anywhere on the drives, or as services running).

We *do* know what remote port the forward is going to, and we *do* see traffic from the Windows server (on which the application is installed) to the remote port.

When the connection happens seems to be random, and very short lived. I'm trying to capture *what* process is making this connection and *where* it lives on the Windows server.

I wrote the following script to that end, but I'm by no means married to the idea of using Powershell if there's a better method:

```
$foundConnections = @()
$foundProcesses = @()

while($true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    $connections = Get-NetTCPConnection -RemotePort 30117 -ErrorAction Ignore
    if($connections -ne $null)
    {
        if($connections.Count -ne $null -and $connections.Count -gt 1)
        {
            foreach($aConnection in $connections)
            {
                $foundConnections += $aConnection
                $process = Get-Process -Id $aConnection.OwningProcess
                Write-Output ($process)
                $foundProcesses += $process
                Add-Content -Path C:\Temp\procs.csv -Value ((Get-Date).ToString() + "," + $process.Name + "," + $process)
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $foundConnections += $connections
            $process = Get-Process -Id $connections.OwningProcess
            Write-Output ($process)
            $foundProcesses += $process
            Add-Content -Path C:\Temp\procs.csv -Value ((Get-Date).ToString() + "," + $process.Name + "," + $process)
        }

    }
}
```

...Which eventually does spot the traffic, but the produced csv looks like this:

...
11/8/2017 8:25:06 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:06 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:07 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:07 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:07 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:07 AM,,

11/8/2017 8:25:14 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:14 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:15 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)
11/8/2017 8:25:16 AM,Idle,System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle)

...

...Several hundred lines of that.

How can I determine a process running if I know the remote port it's using, and it running does not seem to hold to a schedule, and the connection is very short lived?

Comment: I wonder if the PID you're getting is empty, which is why `Get-Process` is returning "Idle" (aka PID 0). Try getting rid of your `ForEach-Object` and do `netstat -ab >> C:\Temp\procs.txt` instead (script will need to run elevated).

Comment: @root you are close. `$aConnection.OwningProcess` would return 0 if `$aConnection.State` is e.g. `TimeWait` (_Waiting for enough time to pass to be sure the remote TCP received the acknowledgment of its connection termination request_), see [`MSFT_NetTCPConnection` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396); you could see it running `netstat -o 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using use a packet capture tool like Netmon (aka Network Monitor). Use a capture filter which will keep it small, filter based on the target port & IP, let it run for a few hours and you should see the process. Then just search disk for that exe. 
Netmon DL https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865
Netmon was replaced by the newer "Message Analyzer" which I have not used as much, some people also like Wireshark, but I'm not sure Wireshark gets down to the process level like the MS capture tools do.

If they are being forwarded via a scheduled task... the tree view of the task scheduler can be tedious for searches. But there is also a CLI for tasks with powershell `Get-ScheduledTask` which returns all the jobs names, and the path to the task. Maybe worth looking that over.